# bitmap min and max values in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a `bitmap` object in C# which is created as follows:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(_currentImage.Width, _currentImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
```

The bitmap gets filled by a third party function call and it is loaded with the correct image.

Now, I want to do some simple image statistics on it. Is there a convenient way to query the minimum and maximum value in the image, say in the RED channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple version that reads all the 48bpp pixels and does something with Red as an example (not tested)

```
unsafe static ushort MaxRed(Bitmap bm)
{
    var bd = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bm.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
    ushort maxRed = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < bm.Height; y++)
    {
        ushort* ptr = (ushort*)(bd.Scan0 + y * bd.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < bm.Width; x++)
        {
            ushort b = *ptr++;
            ushort g = *ptr++;
            ushort r = *ptr++;
            maxRed = Math.Max(maxRed, r);
        }
    }
    bm.UnlockBits(bd);
    return maxRed;
}
```

Unsafe because it's easier than using `Marshal`, but you can convert it to that, for example using `ReadInt16(IntPtr, Int32)` or by copying the whole image into an array (which of course doubles the space requirements).

Comment: How can I make this solution work with an `Format24bppRgb` image? Because it returns a wrong result when I change nothing (clear why) and an exception when I change the `PixelFormat`. But this solution is two times faster as my solution which uses `LockBits` and its 6 times faster as the solution with `GetPixel`.

Comment: @NtFreX it's reading 2 bytes per channel now, that wouldn't be appropriate for 24bpp, so change the `ushort`s to `byte`s (most importantly the pointers).

Comment: Hm clever. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @harold the image format you are using prevents you from using [`GetPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx) as this method returns a `Color` which internaly stores its rgb values as byte's. And as you are using an image with 48 bits per pixel (16 bit = 2 byte per color) a byte is to small.

So you need to work with the [`LockBits`](https://www.google.ch/search?q=bitmap+LockBits&oq=bitmap+LockBits&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i59j0l2.1199j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) method which returns an [`BitmapData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata(v=vs.110).aspx) object. The property `Scan0` of this return object represents a pointer to the first byte in the data of the locked range.

I came up with the following method to get the maximum r value. It will work with the two specified formats in the `PixelFormats` property and more formats can easily be added.

```
public class PixelFormatData
{
    // example => rgb are three values,
    //         => argb are four values
    public int ValueCount { get; set; }
    public int BitsPerPixel { get; set; }

    public PixelFormatData(int valueCount, int bitsPerPixel)
    {
        ValueCount = valueCount;
        BitsPerPixel = bitsPerPixel;
    }
}

public static readonly Dictionary<PixelFormat, PixelFormatData> PixelFormats = new Dictionary<PixelFormat, PixelFormatData>
{
    { PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, new PixelFormatData(3, 24) },
    { PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb, new PixelFormatData(3, 48) }
};

public static IEnumerable<byte[]> GetBytes(Bitmap image, int bytesPerPixel)
{
    var imageData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
    var ptr = imageData.Scan0;
    var imageSize = image.Width * image.Height;
    for (int x = 0; x < imageSize; x++)
    {
        yield return ptr.CopyAndMove(bytesPerPixel);
    }
    image.UnlockBits(imageData);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> GetValues(Bitmap image, int valueIndex)
{
    if (!PixelFormats.ContainsKey(image.PixelFormat))
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(image.PixelFormat));

    var pixelFormatData = PixelFormats[image.PixelFormat];

    if (valueIndex < 0 || valueIndex >= pixelFormatData.ValueCount)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(valueIndex));

    int bytesPerPixel = pixelFormatData.BitsPerPixel / 8,
        bytesPerValue = bytesPerPixel / pixelFormatData.ValueCount;

    return GetBytes(image, bytesPerPixel)
        .Select(bytes =>
            bytes.Skip(bytesPerValue * valueIndex)
                 .Take(bytesPerValue)
                 .RightPad(4))
        .Select(valueData => BitConverter.ToInt32(valueData.ToArray(), 0));
}
```

Those two extension methods are required to use the code.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static List<T> RightPad<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int total)
    {
        var list = collection.ToList();
        while (list.Count < 8)
            list.Add(default(T));
        return list;
    }
}

public static class IntPtrExtensions
{
    public static byte[] CopyAndMove(this IntPtr ptr, int count)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, count);
        ptr += count;
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used.

```
using (var file = new FileStream(@"C:\mypath\myPicture.png", FileMode.Open))
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file);
    // the color is saved in the followig format (gbr) so the 
    // red color is index 2
    Console.WriteLine(GetValues(image, 2).Max());
}
```

I've tested it with an `Format24bppRgb` image.

---

If the bits per pixel are 8 and bellow you can also use `GetPixel` to check for every pixel. It is just about 3 times slower then the method above.

```
byte highestRed = 0;
using (var file = new FileStream(@"C:\mypath\mypicture.jpg", FileMode.Open))
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file);
    for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            var color = image.GetPixel(x, y);
            if(highestRed < color.R)
                highestRed = color.R;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably a bad idea for a Format48bppRgb image like OP has

Comment: @harold Can you explain me what the problem would be? (here to learn)

Comment: Because it's 48 bits per pixel, 16 bits per channel, it won't fit in a byte. `GetPixel` is also very slow, but that's like a bonus-critique..

Comment: I heard GetPixel() and methods like this are really slow...Also can I cast this safely to unsigned short or such type in C#?

Comment: @Luca I've extended my answer. Maybe it helps

Comment: Your code works perfectly for the maximum, what additional is required to obtain the minimum values?

Comment: @BillMcDonald You could just change `Console.WriteLine(GetValues(image, 2).Max());` to `Console.WriteLine(GetValues(image, 2).Min());`